# nginx location deny file extension not allowed by regex

Tags: regex, nginx, pcre, nginx-location

On **nginx** I'm trying to allow only some extensions and deny **all the others** like gif,zip,exe,**php** for a given subtree.

I'd like to use a regular expression to define the **allowed** extensions.

Here's my try using a *negative look ahead*:

```
location /wp-content/userimages/ {
  location ~* (\.(?!(jpg|png|jpeg)))$ {
    deny all;;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(\.(?!(jpg|png|jpeg)))$` regex matches a `.` at the end of the input as there is no consuming pattern between `\.` and `$`. You need to add a consuming pattern for the extension, e.g. `[^.]+` that matches any 1+ chars other than `.`:

```
\.(?!(png|jpe?g)$)[^.]+$
```

Note I shrank the `jpeg|jpg` into `jpe?g` and added the end of string check to the lookahead so that extensions starting with the forbidden extensions (like `png2` (if you ever come across it)) could be matched and `png` could not.

Comment: Yes, very cleaver, the **$** inside the look-ahead and at the end!